# Open files limit server can support

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, server

I am continuously getting Socket connection problem (too many open files) in tomcats catalina.out. When I do

```
ulimit -n
```

I get 1024. Is there a way I can find whats the maximum number of open files the server can support before increasing the limit. I don't want to arbitrarily increase the limit to a value the server cant support. I am searching, I can find how to increase it but cant find how to figure out server limitations.

```
cat /proc/version
```

Linux version 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Feb 12 00:41:43 UTC 2014

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

As pointed out by my friend in the answer below.

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

I want to know this limit (maximum number of open files) the system supports. So I can set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find System Max Open file limit here:

```
$cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
796516
```

Note: you can change above limit too, but there is no hard rule how much max support, it all depend on how much resource you have etc.

**Update**: RHEL 5 has a maximum value of 1048576 (2^20) for this limit, You can patch your kernel and modify that limit to make it whatever number you like.

More info: https://serverfault.com/questions/192313/how-does-rhel-5-linux-kernel-2-6-18-determine-the-default-fs-file-max-setting

Comment: Yes I did that but I can set any value I want here. I want to know whats my system(server) capacity. How many open files my system can support.